# ostringstream is empty after inserting output to it

Tags: c++, stl, ostringstream

I have a strange issue where ostringstream is empty even though I insert an output to it.
Here is my code:

```
//logger.h

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using std::string;


class BasicLogger {
public:
    BasicLogger(const string name);
    BasicLogger(const BasicLogger& basicLogger);
    ~BasicLogger();

    template<class T>
    BasicLogger& operator<<(const T &msg){
        std::cout << "msg is: " << msg << std::endl;
        mBuf << msg;
        std::cout << "mBuf is: " << mBuf.str() << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }


private:
    string mName;
    std::ostringstream mBuf;
};


class Logger {
public:
    Logger();
    ~Logger();
    BasicLogger info();
    BasicLogger error();

private:
    BasicLogger mInfoLogger;
    BasicLogger mErrorLogger;

};
```

---

```
//logger.cpp

#include "logger.h"

BasicLogger::BasicLogger(const string name):
    mName(name) { }

BasicLogger::BasicLogger(const BasicLogger& otherLogger) {
    this->mName = otherLogger.mName;
    this->mBuf << otherLogger.mBuf.rdbuf();
}

BasicLogger::~BasicLogger() { }

Logger::Logger(): 
    mInfoLogger("[INFO]"),
    mErrorLogger("[ERROR]") {}

Logger::~Logger() {};

BasicLogger Logger::info() {
    return mInfoLogger;
}

BasicLogger Logger::error() {
    return mErrorLogger;
}
```

---

```
//main.cpp

#include "logger.h"

int main() {
    Logger logger;
    logger.info() << "Hellooo";
}
```

---

The output is

```
msg is: Hellooo
mBuf is:
```

Comment: `info()` returns by value, so you get a copy of the logger.

Comment: @BoPersson You're right! I didn't pay attention to that... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @BoPersson already gave you the solution, I would like to explain what happened here, and why your output is empty, even though you are adding to `ostringstream` on the line just before you display its content.

I think when you attempted to return `mInfoLogger` by value, the compiler complained about not being able to return it because copy constructor was deleted. The reason it was deleted because `ostringstream` member you have is non-copyable.

So you provided custom copy constructor and attempted to copy the stream this way:

```
this->mBuf << otherLogger.mBuf.rdbuf();
```

Only this does not copy anything as your `rdbuf` is empty and instead sets `failbit` on

> **The failbit**
>
> The streambuf overload of basic_ostream::operator<< if the function
>   inserts no characters.
>   http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate

If you were to check your message insertion like this:

```
if (!(mBuf << msg))
    std::cout << "Not Inserted" << std::endl;
```

You would see `Not Inserted` message printed. There are many ways to make it print the desired message. For example making sure your `rdbuf` buffer is not empty or by resetting the `failbit` before you reuse the `mBuf`, something like `mBuf.clear();` or simply by returning the reference to `mInfoLogger` (and `mErrorLogger`). Then you can safely get rid of your copy constructor.